# Como colocar datos en input, dependiendo del valor de un combobox?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, php7

Tengo un combobox donde hago select a una tabla llamada 'sitios', dentro de esta tabla tengo las columnas (Referencia, Sitio, Domicilio, Telefono, Ciudad) y la columna "Sitio" son los datos que se despliegan en el combobox.
Lo que no e podido hacer es que *dependiendo del "Sitio que seleccione, se coloque el valor de (Referencia, Domicilio, Telefono, Ciudad)* en un input cada uno.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $serv = "localhost";
        $dataB = "cdv1";
        
        $mysqli = new mysqli($serv, $user, $pass, $dataB);
        
        ?>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Solicita tu Cuenta</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/solicitud.css">
<!--        <script src="JS/soloLetras.js"></script>-->
        <script src="JS/soloLetrasv2.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/keyCURP.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/soloNumeros.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/letraCapital.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="formSoli" action="Confirmacion.php" class="formSolicitud" method="POST">
            <h1 class="formTitulo">Solicitud</h1>
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">

            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Paterno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeP" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Materno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeM" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ejemplo: Ingeniero en ..." title="Campo Opcional" maxlength="80" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloLetrasv2(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Puesto</label>
            <input type="text" name="puesto" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Departamento</label>
            <input type="text" name="depa" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <!--            sitio-->
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Sitio</label>
            <select name="sitio" id="sitio" class="formSelect" title="Seleccione el sitio correspondiente" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=6;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
                <?php
                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    echo '<option>'.$valores[Sitio].'</option>';
                }
                
                ?>
            </select>
            
            <!--            input hidden-->
            <input type="text" name="referencia" id="ref" value="">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="domicilio" id="dom" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="telefono" id="tel" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
            
            <label for="" class="formLabel">CURP</label>
            <input type="text" name="curp" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" size="18" maxlength="18" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return keyCURP(event);" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">   
            <label for="" class="formLabel">N°Seguro Social</label>
            <input type="text" name="numSS" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Matricula</label>
            <input type="text" name="matri" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            
            <input type="submit" src="Confirmacion.php" class="formButton" value="Enviar Datos">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

vi un ejemplo con Json pero no lo pude adaptar a lo que busco, un saludo y desde ya gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbz3x.png)

Comment: podrias pasar el html css y js para ayudarte mejor

Comment: pase el archivo muy amable por la sugerencia, espero sea mas entendible, saludos

Answer (score 0):

mira a ver si algo como esto te puede servir, lo he hecho un poco a ciegas sin poder probar, asi que seguramente haya errores de sintaxis pero la idea creo que se puede ver.

Básicamente la idea es:

- Antes del bucle while, declaramos un array javascript vacio
- en el bucle while, vamos llenando ese array con objetos de cada uno de los sitios
- En el select añadimos onchange para que dispare la función que cambiara los datos de los inputs
- En la función, se comprueba que valor tiene el select y en funcion a eso, se cargan los datos en los inputs correspondientes.

Un saludo, espero que te sirva de ayuda

```

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($serv, $user, $pass, $dataB);

    ?>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Solicita tu Cuenta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/solicitud.css">
    <script src="JS/soloLetrasv2.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/keyCURP.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/soloNumeros.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/letraCapital.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form name="formSoli" action="Confirmacion.php" class="formSolicitud" method="POST">
        <h1 class="formTitulo">Solicitud</h1>
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">

        <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Paterno</label>
        <input type="text" name="apeP" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Materno</label>
        <input type="text" name="apeM" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Titulo</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ejemplo: Ingeniero en ..." title="Campo Opcional" maxlength="80" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloLetrasv2(event);">
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Puesto</label>
        <input type="text" name="puesto" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Departamento</label>
        <input type="text" name="depa" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
        <!--            sitio-->
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Sitio</label>
        <select onchange="loadDataOnInputs()" name="sitio" id="sitio" class="formSelect" title="Seleccione el sitio correspondiente" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=6;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
          <script>var sitios=[];</script>
            <?php
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?><script>
                  let unSitio = {
                    Referencia:'<?php echo $valores[Referencia];?>',
                    Sitio:'<?php echo $valores[Sitio];?>',
                    Domicilio:'<?php echo $valores[Domicilio];?>',
                    Telefono:'<?php echo $valores[Telefono];?>',
                    Ciudad:'<?php echo $valores[Ciudad];?>'
                  }
                  sitios.push(unSitio);
                </script> <?php
                echo '<option value="'.$valores[Referencia].'">'.$valores[Sitio].'</option>';
            }

            ?>
        </select>

        <!--            input hidden-->
        <input type="text" name="referencia" id="ref" value="">

        <input type="hidden" name="domicilio" id="dom" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="telefono" id="tel" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="">

        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">

        <label for="" class="formLabel">CURP</label>
        <input type="text" name="curp" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" size="18" maxlength="18" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return keyCURP(event);" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">   
        <label for="" class="formLabel">N°Seguro Social</label>
        <input type="text" name="numSS" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
        <label for="" class="formLabel">Matricula</label>
        <input type="text" name="matri" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">

        <input type="submit" src="Confirmacion.php" class="formButton" value="Enviar Datos">
    </form>
    <script>
      function loadDataOnInputs(){
        let sitio = document.querySelector("#sitio");

        sitios.forEach(element=>{
          if (element.Referencia == sitio.value){
            let refe = document.querySelector('#ref');
            let dom = document.querySelector('#dom');
            let tel = document.querySelector('#tel');
            let ciudad = document.querySelector('#ciudad');

            refe.value = element.Referencia;
            dom.value = element.Domicilio;
            tel.value = element.Telefono;
            ciudad.value = element.Ciudad;
          }
        })
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

```

Comment: primero que nada muchas gracias Athos Oc, probe el codigo y no me funciono, trate cambiando el onchange que ya tenia en el select pero aun asi no me coloca la referencia correspondiente en el input.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada muchas gracias, mira lo intente asi, cheque si habia algun error en sintaxis y lo vi todo en orden, solo cambie un onchange que ya tenia por otro tipo de evento y le deje el onchange al script, que puede ser lo que este aplicando mal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $serv = "localhost";
        $dataB = "cdv1";
        
        $mysqli = new mysqli($serv, $user, $pass, $dataB);
        
        ?>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Solicita tu Cuenta</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/solicitud.css">
<!--        <script src="JS/soloLetras.js"></script>-->
        <script src="JS/soloLetrasv2.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/keyCURP.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/soloNumeros.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/letraCapital.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="formSoli" action="Confirmacion.php" class="formSolicitud" method="POST">
            <h1 class="formTitulo">Solicitud</h1>
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">

            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Paterno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeP" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Materno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeM" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ejemplo: Ingeniero en ..." title="Campo Opcional" maxlength="80" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloLetrasv2(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Puesto</label>
            <input type="text" name="puesto" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Departamento</label>
            <input type="text" name="depa" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <!--            sitio-->
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Sitio</label>
            <select onchange="loadDataOnInputs()" name="sitio" id="sitio" class="formSelect" title="Seleccione el sitio correspondiente" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=6;}" onmouseout='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
<!--                onchange='this.size=0;'-->
                <script>var sitios=[];</script>
                <?php
//                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
//                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
//                    echo '<option>'.$valores[Sitio].'</option>';
//                //mejor lo quite del option (value="'.$valores[Referencia].'")
//                }
                
                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    ?><script>
                    let unSitio = {
                        Referencia:'<?php echo $valores[Referencia];?>',
                        Sitio:'<?php echo $valores[Sitio];?>',
                        Domicilio:'<?php echo $valores[Domicilio];?>',
                        Telefono:'<?php echo $valores[Telefono];?>',
                        Ciudad:'<?php echo $valores[Ciudad];?>',
                    }
            sitios.push(unSitio);
                    </script><?php
                    echo '<option value="'.$valores[Referencia].'">'.$valores[Sitio].'</option>';
                }
                
                ?>
            </select>
            
            
            <!--            input hidden-->
            <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" value="">
            
            <input type="text" name="dom" id="dom" value="">
            <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" value="">
            <input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
            
            <label for="" class="formLabel">CURP</label>
            <input type="text" name="curp" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" size="18" maxlength="18" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return keyCURP(event);" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">   
            <label for="" class="formLabel">N°Seguro Social</label>
            <input type="text" name="numSS" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Matricula</label>
            <input type="text" name="matri" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            
            <input type="submit" src="Confirmacion.php" class="formButton" value="Enviar Datos">
        </form>
        
        <script>
            function loadDataOnInputs() {
                let sitio = document.querySelector('#sitio');
                
                sitios.forEach(element=>{
                    if (element.Referencia == sitio.value) {
                        let ref = document.querySelector('#ref');
                        let dom = document.querySelector('#dom');
                        let tel = document.querySelector('#tel');
                        let ciudad = document.querySelector('#ciudad');
                        
                        ref.value = element.Referencia;
                        dom.value = element.Domicilio;
                        tel.value = element.Telefono;
                        ciudad.value = element.Ciudad;
                    }
                })
            }
            </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```